# Printing a char in C with printf wont print

Tags: c, char, printf

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[50];
    int pass = 0;

    printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
    gets(buff);
    char str[80];
    strcat(str, "nw");
    strcat(str, "ww");
    strcat(str, "io");
    strcat(str, "oi");

    char str2[22];
    strcat(str2, "jm");
    strcat(str2, "qw");
    strcat(str2, "ef");
    strcat(str2, "io");
    strcat(str2, "nw");
    strcat(str2, "ce");
    strcat(str2, "or");
    strcat(str2, "ww");
    strcat(str2, "qf");
    strcat(str2, "ej");
    strcat(str2, "oi");


    if(strcmp(buff, str))
    {
        /*  we sf  as  df er fd xc yyu er we nm hj ui ty as asd qwe er t yu as sd df rt ty qw sd password    */

        printf ("\n Wrong Password \n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf ("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }

    if(pass)
    {
        printf ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n%s", str2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it I get:

```
root@images:~# ./root.flag

 Enter the password :
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

 Wrong Password







Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It prints the newline characters but not the value store in str2. How do I get str2 to print to the screen? Im fairly new to C so I have no clue why this is not working. It is likely something simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: I don't see a `%c` conversion type specifier in your code.

Answer (score 5):

buff is only 50 characters but you enter 131 "A"'s so you have undefined behavior.
Also str2 is only 22 characters, it needs to be 23 and should be '\0' NULL terminated to print it.
 In fact you shouldn't be strcat'ing to it before it's initialized.  Try `str2[23] ={0};`

the function strcat(str, new) looks for the end of the string str to begin adding the characters in new.  The end of a string is defined as '\0' or zero.  You need to initialize local variables to be sure they have the value you want.  the code for that is `str1[80]={0};` and `str2[23]={0};`

Comment: the `strcat`s are also UB since `str` and `str2` are not initialized

Comment: @yano got it, just updated the answer.

Comment: Uh lol can someone show me what this all means in code?

Comment: Ohh ok yea that helps

Comment: so "char str[9] = {0};" or just "str[9] = {0};"   before I do the strcat?

Comment: `char str[9]={0};` after it's declared you can only initialize individual members like `str[0]='\0'`

Comment: Ahh ok I think I got it. So thats functionally the same as char str2[23] = {'j','m','q','w','e','f','i','o','n','w','c','e','o','r','w','w','q','f','e','j','o','i','\0'};

Comment: Yes, that's probably prefered since you're only using strcat to initialize I'd prefer to see it initialized as `str2[23] = {'j','m','q','w','e','f','i','o','n','w','c','e','o','r','w'‌​,'w','q','f','e','j'‌​,'o','i','\0'};` it's easier to understand.

Comment: Awesome, cool thanks!

Comment: Instead of initializing the string and using the first strcat() to append to an empty string, you could use strcpy() instead of the first strcat()